# Exception while running Sqlite query!

Tags: android, sqlite

This is the error i get:

```
 **ERROR/Database(13775): Failure 1 (near "s": syntax error)**
```

while i try to execute the following query:

```
myDB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + tableName + " (" + column[1] + "," + column[2] + "," + column[3] + "," + column[4] + ","
                                + column[5] + "," + column[6] + "," + column[7] + "," + column[8] + ",type ) VALUES('" + url + "','" + title + "','" + summary + "','" + imageUrl + "','" + completeStoryUrl + "','" + date + "','" + imageString + "','" + body + "','" + type + "')");
```

These values are being stored in Db by parsing an xml having RSS feeds like objects. few items are stored but on some i get this exception. Is there a problem of query of the data being sent to tha query..??? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain

Comment: You might need to escape the INSERT values - 
[this thread might help][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432063/how-to-escape-unsupported-character-in-sqlite-on-android

Comment: why not make the string up first and print it out.

Comment: Thanks all of u, it was quite an iformative discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the actual query that is being executed, I would guess that one of the fields being inserted contains a " character, which is breaking the SQL statement.

for example imagine if the value of summary was

```
This string need"s to be escaped
```

As Michalis said, you need to escape the values being inserted ( replace any special characters )

If I were you, I would log the actual string query that is being executed. Then take a look in logcat at it and you should see why it is failing.

Answer (score 1):

You should **never** create a SQL command with string manipulation because there is the danger of a SQL injection. There are methods to safely format the command with parameter.

In Java there is for example the `java.sql.PreparedStatement` class.

Using such a conventional method should fix your syntax error, too.

Comment: Its on android. Java.sql.preparedstatement doesn't apply. Morever, this should be in the comment section..This is not an answer.

Comment: I cannot comment because of my rep. There are ways for a prepared statement on android, too (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433392/how-do-i-use-prepared-statements-in-sqlite-in-android). This was only an example. This is a really important note and should not be voted down!

Comment: My bad. I didn't notice your rep.. Otherwise i wouldn't have downvoted.