# Replacing single quotes with double quotes in Android database insertion statement

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Suppose I have an execquery statement like this:

```
db1.execSQL("insert into "+TABLE_NAME+" values('"name"')");
```

where name is a string variable which contains an apostrophe. For example:

```
name = "tom's database";
```

In this case, I get an SQLITEexception near this statement. I am certain that this is because of that single quote.

How to modify this such that the statement does not cause a crash and the name get stored in the db with the single quote intact?

I read online that every such single quote has to be prefixed by another single quote.

Can someone provide the code for the same?

Comment: This `name` is static or dynamic?

Comment: `name = name.replace("'", "''");` Note: it's 1 apostropphe replaced by 2 apostrophes.

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/20608753/3330969

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to escape unsupported character in SQLite on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432063/how-to-escape-unsupported-character-in-sqlite-on-android)

Comment: Don't do such things manually, let Java handle it for you. Use [PreperedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Answer (score 3):

Duplicate question. Check [How to escape unsupported character in SQLite on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5432063/how-to-escape-unsupported-character-in-sqlite-on-android)

Use

```
String escapedName = DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString(name);
db1.execSQL("insert into "+TABLE_NAME+" values('" + escapedName + "')");
```

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#sqlEscapeString%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 3):

Escaping the special character in the string literal works but generally it's an error prone approach. It's better to use `?` placeholder and bind arguments, like this:

```
db1.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAME + " VALUES (?)", new String[] { name });
```

or use `insert()` with `ContentValues` which does essentially the same.

Comment: @Iaalto: your knowledge of SQLite always surprises me for its depth. +1

Answer (score 2):

You forgot:

1. To double the string apostrophes (since a apostrophes are the SQL string delimiters).
2. To add the + in the INSERT string to properly add the variable.

So, I'd change the above INSERT statement to:

```
db1.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAME + " VALUES ('" + name.replace("'", "''") + "')");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use "PrepareStatement" to avoid problems

```
SQLiteStatement p = db1.compileStatement("insert into "+TABLE_NAME+" values(?)");
p.bindString(1, name);
p.execute();
```

Other form:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("name", name);
db1.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
```